# Python Numpy - Matrix replaces defined matrix in global matrix.. similar to Matlab

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Does anyone have a quick solution in Python to this problem. In matrix A I wish to replace values in A with a C matrix at a certain location?

```
A=  [ 1 2 3 4 4
      2 3 4 5 3
      4 5 6 7 2
      5 6 7 8 9
      6 7 8 9 0 ]

C=  [ 7 7
      7 7 ]
```

at locations **loc = [3 5]** such that the outcome matrix B looks like the following:

```
B=  [ 1 2 3 4 4
      2 3 4 5 3
      4 5 7 7 7
      5 6 7 8 9
      6 7 7 9 7 ]
```

In Matlab the code is easy:

```
A(loc,loc) = C
```

I have tried it is python:

```
A[loc,loc] = C
```

With no success. Any Ideas? Anyone populating global stiffness matrices with the local stiffness model, would do the operation many times over, but it would usually look like this:

```
K(loc,loc) = K(loc,loc) + C
```

Anyway I hope this is an ok question? I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: Could you give us the code you tried? show the errors

Comment: maybe it's just me, but it's not clear how from the given `A`, `C`, and `loc` you end up with the given `B`. In other words, what operation are you attempting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4,
      2, 3, 4, 5, 3,
      4, 5, 6, 7, 2,
      5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
      6, 7, 8, 9, 0 ]).reshape(5, 5)

B = np.array([60, 70, 80, 90]).reshape(2, 2)

A[2:6:2, 2:6:2] = B # or
A[np.ix_([2, 4], [2, 4])] = B  

print A
```

output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  4]
 [ 2  3  4  5  3]
 [ 4  5 60  7 70]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 6  7 80  9 90]]
```

Comment: Yip.. that is it... MATLAB just lost another finger. Seems to be loosing its final grip on me.... Thank you